# Is a (Radius) WiFi certificate also used by the web browsers (https)?

Tags: tls, wifi

When trying to connect to a "WPA2 Enterprise" (802.1X) protected network (eduroam) MacOS is asking me to accept a Certificate. This certificate is self-signed by the University.

The certificate's purpose #1 is stated as : "Server Authentication ( 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 )". There is no other purpose.
(Extension is "Extended Key Usage ( 2.5.29.37 )".

My question is now: If I accept this certificate would my browser (usually Chorme, sometimes Firefox) also accept https websites signed with this certificate? Maybe those two options available for me do just that:

Extensible Authentication EAP (for WiFi)
X.509 (for Webbrowsers)

Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the certificate as an EAP certificate will not cause it to be accepted for server authentication.  It becomes associated with the EAP profile for 802.1x use.  The two uses determine when the operating system (OS X) considers each one for certificate validation.